# starting my countdown clock when activity is open

Tags: java, android, counter, oncreate, countdowntimer

I am a bit of a keen novice at Android! I have a snippet of code for timer I want to use in my app however it works when the button is clicked and I want it to work when I open the activity that it is on.  I have tried so many solutions but cannot get it to operate.  Would really appreciate any help, I have tried putting an if statement in, I have tried using the onStart, and putting it the OnCreate all with no joy.  The closest I can get is that it just starts with "Time Up!" in the field.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

Button buttonStartTime;                 
TextView textViewShowTime;              
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;          
long totalTimeCountInMilliseconds;      
long timeBlinkInMilliseconds;           
boolean blink;                          

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getReferenceOfViews ();                       
    setActionListeners ();                         

    totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = 60 * 1000;      
    timeBlinkInMilliseconds = 30 * 1000;           
}

private void setActionListeners() {

     buttonStartTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            textViewShowTime.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),     R.style.normalText);

            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
                    long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;

                    if ( leftTimeInMilliseconds < timeBlinkInMilliseconds ) {
                        textViewShowTime.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.blinkText);
                        if ( blink ) {
                            textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
                            textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        blink = !blink;         
                    }
                    textViewShowTime.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 60) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() 
                    textViewShowTime.setText("Time up!");
                    textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
);
}
private void getReferenceOfViews() {
    buttonStartTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartTime);
    textViewShowTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimeCount);
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried allocating countDownTimer at the bottom of onCreate()?

Comment: You could programatically simulate the Button click in *onResume()*.

Comment: I want to remove the button element completely and just have the timer start onCreate of activity.  is it possible to modify the code without the on click or button?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your *onResume()* as :

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    buttonStartTime.performClick();
    super.onResume();
}
```

You should make buttonStartTime a global variable for the class.

Comment: Is there no a way of removing the button element completely and having timer activate when activity opens?